# angular multiple http looping request with time delay

Tags: angularjs

I have an ID array contains with 50+ id.

```
var ids = [
    '3407197',
    '0632706',
    '18275',
    ...,
    ...
]
```

I want to send angular HTTP get request with a loop. Each iteration will delay 10 sec delay. When all the request complete it will notify that request are completed.

I have tried with this code but It executes at once not delaying.

```
function collector(i){
    setTimeout(function() {
        return $http.get('http://example.com/' + ids[i])
          .success(function(data) {
          })
          .error(function(err) {
          })
    },10000);
 }


 $scope.getAllData = function() {
    var promises = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
      promises.push(collector(i));
    }
    return $q.all(promises);
  }

  $scope.getAllData ().then(function(data) {
    $scope.debug = 'done';
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `$timeout`:

```
function getRequest(id) {
    return $http.get('http://example.com/' + id)
        .success(function (data) {})
        .error(function (err) {});   
}

var promise = $timeout();
ids.forEach(function(id) {
     promise = promise.then(function() {
         getRequest(id);
         return $timeout(10000);
     });
});

// not sure if this works
promise.then(function() {
    $scope.debug = 'done';
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response, It is node module what you provided (rx). Please help me in angular way.

Comment: thanks again for your quick response, according to your solution, how to fire an event after all request finished.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but try to register a `.then` callback **after** the `forEach` (see my edit).